# show slave status\G; Last_Error Error 'Field 'paper_content' doesn't have a default value' on query. Default database: 'vhuatu'. Query

Tags: mysql, sql

![enter image description here][1]Mysql master-slave synchronization, she found there was an error in the following locations, when I stick the SQL statements to the mysql command line, found that can perform, I don't know what reason be?

```
Error 'Field 'paper_content' doesn't have a default value' on query. Default database: 'vhuatu'. Query: 'insert into v_exam_paper (name, descrp, uid, tactics, exampaper_type, past_year, past_area, bl_subject, pastpaper_id, com_paper_id, BB103, EB1B1) values ('《国家行测》-智能推送-20140405', null, '8281686', 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAJXTPQuDQAwG4P+S2YJJ7tO1U8HNUVxKlw71LNZJ/O+9LM6+4wUe8oZLxp2+jxd1VFRd9tTU53ovn6Vss5VvbKVhe/bv9UfdOB3NKVzKgWEhkPBtDBEWCRKqweEig4IFnSMx1qMKacFU6rE/N6CwcLAANzFywiY3ge1uvY+AphI4lYCpTFy5qOkPazv8uekDAAA=', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1396642419', "0")'
```

Comment: what kind of error you getting, if you can paste the error

Comment: where is the paper_content field in table,..

Answer (score 0):

## What does the error mean?

You are inserting values in a table but, from the description of the error and the query in it, you are not specifying a value for the field `paper_conent` and the table definition doesn't indicate a default value for the field either. That makes the query fail.

If you expect your queries to be similar to the one that fails (and it makes sense for your data model) you should alter the table to include a default value for that field. Otherwise, you should correct the queries you are executing to include the column and field specifically.

## What is the problem?

On the other hand, based on the fact that you are getting that error in the slave (but not on the master) it would appear to indicate that the database schemas may not be the same. Maybe when you did your initial data import, part of the table definitions were not copied correctly. Or, for some reason, the statements to alter/create the tables adding the default value of that field did not replicate as expected.

Review the table definitions in your master and then in your slave and make sure that they match.